# Is there a way to create a texture atlas from an animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

I would like to be able to create a texture atlas from the rendered frames of an animation. In my case, the animation will be 6 images that are 1024x1024 pixels, and I would like to make a 3x2 atlas of them, so a single 3072x2048 image. Doing this manually one time would be fine, but I need to do it 32 times.

Maybe this is possible with the compositor? Not really sure.

Comment: You are probably looking for a "sprite sheet" ... [probably related](https://github.com/theloneplant/blender-spritesheets)